# Installation of Skype is blocked

Tags: windows-xp, skype, blocking

On my office laptop running on XP, installation of Skype is blocked. Also I'm not able to download the software from internet.

So I downloaded the software from a different machine and tried copying it to my desktop. But during copy, the software 'skype' got deleted from my pen drive itself.

How is this done? And how can I get rid of this?

Comment: If you're using your **office** laptop to download and install Skype, it's possible there might be some software preventing you from obtaining and installed what your IT department considers as "3rd-party software."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/skype_portable (You will NEED a Pc with active internet connection, since first time it'll download the necessary files. THEN just take your pendrive and there you go.)

Comment: I was able to download the file along with its necessary files. But when i double click the exe, i got an error dialog "Could not Skype.exe and you need to re install". Also the entire size of the SkypePoratble folder is just 144KB

Comment: Yes because it would download the real data. Well. Wait a second. Downloading it, creating an ultra compressed 7z package. :)

Comment: Here it is. Virus scan log (BitDefender, uptodate, just done it): http://pastebin.com/vuFy0dYy || AND the file: http://shiki.hu/stuff/SkypePort7Zselfextract.exe (LZMA2 compressed, Ultra profile, 66mb memory will be needed for uncompress).

Comment: Anything ? Did you try the package?